# How to pass 2 arguments to jquery Find() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have created a table that displays data, when user click on `Update` button it turns table cells into input field where user can enter the data..

When i click on edit button it successfully changes 1 cell of table into input field, but i am unable to understand how to change other cells of the table, i need to change all cells of the table in single click.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var input = $('<input type="text" />');
    input.val(html);
    $(this).html(input);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">                                       
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Username </td>
      <td>Password </td>
      <td>Role </td>

      <td>                                                        

        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>                                        
</table>
```

I have added the example on `JSFiddle` kindly guide me how to achieve this.

https://jsfiddle.net/tahakirmani/g7vrskpz/3/

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Your `find` is selecting only the second TD; why not select all of them?

Comment: i need to find first 3 not all of the elements

Comment: So add a class to the the ones you want selected and select by that class.

Comment: thanks ! :) It did the trick :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `nth-child(2)` from the selector.  `nth-child(2)` causes only the nth (in this case, second) element to be selected and looped through / replaced by an input box.

https://jsfiddle.net/g7vrskpz/4/

```
 $(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function() {
     var html = $(this).html();
     var input = $('<input type="text" />');
     input.val(html);
     $(this).html(input);
   });

 });
```

Edit: First 3 only

https://jsfiddle.net/g7vrskpz/5/

```
 $(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
     var html = $(this).html();
     var input = $('<input type="text" />');
     input.val(html);
     $(this).html(input);
   });

 });
```

Comment: I don't want to find all of them, i just need to find first 3 elements

Comment: you could do `td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)`.  `,` concatenates selectors.